# protect two variables with atomic in a multi-threading environement

Tags: c++, atomic, lock-free

//Thread 1

```
std::uint64_t getAndResetProcessingTimeInMicro()
{
    auto value = m_cumulatedProcessingTimeCount.load(boost::memory_order_acquire);

    if (value == 0)
        return 0;
    auto processingTime = m_cumulatedProcessingTime.load(boost::memory_order_relaxed);

    resetProcessingTimeInMicro();

    return processingTime / value;
}
```

//Thread 2

```
void addProcessingTimeInMicro(std::uint64_t processedTime)
{ 
    m_cumulatedProcessingTime.fetch_add(processedTime, boost::memory_order_relaxed); 
    //ctxt switch here  //-----HERE------
    m_cumulatedProcessingTimeCount.fetch_add(1, boost::memory_order_release);
}
```

Thread1 compute the average of the processing time, Thread 2 accumulate processing time.

I would like to get the insurance that a context switch can't corrompt the data at HERE place without introduce a lock, can I achieve this result by using atomic object ?

Comment: not sure, what you are asking, atomics don't prevent a context switch in any way. Neither does a mutex.

Comment: @MikeMB : you right i have edited

Comment: I was thinking of removing access of m_cumulatedProcessingTime and m_cumulatedProcessingTimeCount from Thread1. instead you can use a boost lock free queue between thread 1 and thread 2, where thread 2 pushes a struct {processedTime, bost::memory_order_release+1} and you make only Thread 2 push that data onto the lock free queue. Thread 1 only pulls data out from the queue and computes the average.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do two different atomic operations together you need a mutex both when you write and when you read them. Mutexes don't prevent context switches, but used this way guarantee that you don't access half updated states.

Alternatively, if you really don't want to use a mutex, you could use some of the 64 bits of a single uint64_t to store the count (say the lower 8).
Then you would

```
m_cumulatedProcessingTime.fetch_add((processedTime << 8) + 1, boost::memory_order_release);
```

and then retrieve it

```
auto value = m_cumulatedProcessingTimeCount.load(boost::memory_order_acquire);
auto time = value >> 8;
auto count = value & 0xff;
```

Comment: yes i knew that, so there is no miracle , I will do like that thanks

Comment: If the two variables can be located next to each other in memory, you can change them both at the same time with a single compare and swap.  Alternately you can put your variables into a struct.  Copy the old struct, change the variables, and then compare and swap a single pointer to the new struct.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but you probably don't want to.

You need an [atomic shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic) to the struct that holds both variables. The process for reading is just to copy the `shared_ptr` atomically and look at the struct it points to. The process for writing is:

1. Read the atomic `shared_ptr`.
2. Allocate (using `std::make_shared`) a new struct containing the new values for both variables based on the ones in the struct.
3. Attempt an atomic compare/exchange to set the atomic shared_ptr to point to your new struct.
4. If the compare/exchange succeeds, you are done.
5. Free the new structure you created and go back to step 1. (You are guaranteed some other writer made forward progress.)

You really don't want to do this though. Just use a lock.

Answer (score 0):

make a union like this:

```
union CData {
  struct {
    __int32   a;
    __int16   c;
    __int16   d:2,
              e:14;
    // you get the idea...
  }
  __int64     n64;
}
```

Use all the variables using the struct members, do the atomic stuff with n64.

Comment: This is undefined behavior in c++. You can only read what you put into a union.

Comment: copy the union using n64.  Access it and change it using a,c,d,e.